# How to implement multivariate regularized linear regression in Dlib?

Tags: c++, dlib

I implemented simple linear regression in [Dlib](http://dlib.net/) as a single-layer perceptron with MSE-loss with a single output. The network type is:

```
dlib::loss_mean_squared<dlib::fc<1,dlib::input<dlib::matrix<float>>>>
```

Now I want to modify the loss function to add L1 regularizer. Is there a simple way to do it? As I understand, there's no ready-to-use loss layer for that in Dlib?

Also, is it ok to implement linear regression in Dlib this way, or are there more appropriate primitives in Dlib that would calculate regression coefficients analytically, e.g. like `LinearRegression` or `Lasso` from scikit-learn?

**UPD:** Seems like [dlib::rr_trainer](http://dlib.net/ml.html#rr_trainer) (ridge linear regression, L2 regularization) is roughly what I need. But I can't find out how to make it predict multiple outputs. If I supply a vector of samples as a second argument to `train()` function, where each sample is a column-matrix `dlib::matrix<N,1>` of target outputs, it segfaults. So far it worked only for a single output, i.e. each output sample is a `float`.